# Can you eval or equivalent in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, eval

If i had a list of question numbers

```
var questions =  new List<int> { 2, 4, 8 };
```

Is it possible to have a query that does something like this in linq?

```
var results = new List<Answer>();

foreach (var qNum in questions)
{
   results.AddRange(Answers.Where(x => eval(x.Question+qNum) == "Yes"));
}
```

So this would look up the answer for x.Question2, x.Question4 and x.Question8.

### Addendum

Currently i am doing this:

```
    var questionAnswers = new List<Answer>();
var Q2 = Questions.Where (x => x.MainQ2.ToUpper() == "NO")
    .Select(x => new Answer { QuestionNumber = 2, AnswerText = x.MainTextQ2, User_Id = x.User_Id });

var Q4 = Questions.Where (x => x.MainQ4.ToUpper() == "NO")
    .Select(x => new Answer { QuestionNumber = 4, AnswerText = x.MainTextQ4, User_Id = x.User_Id });

var Q8 = Questions.Where (x => x.MainQ8.ToUpper() == "NO")
    .Select(x => new Answer { QuestionNumber = 8, AnswerText = x.MainTextQ8, User_Id = x.User_Id });

questionAnswers.AddRange(Q2);
questionAnswers.AddRange(Q4);
questionAnswers.AddRange(Q8);

questionAnswers.GroupBy (a => a.QuestionNumber).Dump();


public class Answer
{
    public int QuestionNumber {get;set;}
    public string AnswerText {get;set;}
    public string User_Id {get;set;}
}
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand what the `eval` is supposed to do here.

Comment: eval would evaluate the property name in the case of the first loop this would be "x.Question2", then "x.Question4"

Comment: Answers is a very bad table in a database that i have to do some reporting on, it has fields like this Question1Answer, Question2Answer etc... I only need to report on a select few of the questions where the answer is no.

Comment: Added real implementation to explain why i am trying to do this terrible thing :)

Comment: Are you using LINQ to Objects, Linq to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: Currently Linq to SQl in LinqPad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* manually build up an expression that accesses the requisite property using the methods in [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356138.aspx) and pass that to `Where` (possibly compiling it first if results is indeed an 
`IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable`).

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/8sJpx)**.

But *why* would you do this? Placing the values you want to access in a collection is so much better than putting them in individual properties. Perhaps you should improve the model so that this problem does not need to be solved at all?

Comment: I have inherited a terribly designed DB that needs some reporting doing on it. My implementation is not very DRY (see addendum) at all and wondered back to the days when i did ActionScript where i could "eval" variable names and wondered if i could do the same here.

Comment: @Kohan: I added a live example to demonstrate. You will have to make some minor changes to run it on an `IQueryable` (do not call `Compile()`, make an `Expression<Func<...>>` instead of a `Func<...>`).

Comment: Interesting, I didnt think to do it this way, but as you have proved it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic.cs AKA DynamicQuery AKA [Dynamic Expression API](http://nuget.org/packages/DynamicQuery)

Using that, you can input a string in place of the where expression:

```
Answers.Where("Question"+qNum+"=\"Yes\"")
```

In the background, it will create something akin to Jon's answer, i.e. a dynamically created Expression, which should be suitable for most LINQ providers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not directly!

`x.Question` should evaluate to an Array of Strings, (or perhaps `IDictionary<int,string>`) then you would be able to do:

```
var results = new List<Answers>();

foreach (var qNum in questions)
{
   results.AddRange(Answers.Where(x => x.Question[qNum] == "Yes"));
}
```